# Meteor - onCreateUser Ajax callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, meteor

In the `Accounts.onCreateUser` function of Meteor, I would like to make an ajax request to get the user details from the Twitter API. While the actual Twitter call works fine and retrieves the expected data, I am unable to return this as the ajax call is done asynchronously. Here is where I'm at:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {

    user.profile = "";
    Twitter.get.userinfo({ screen_name: 'username'}, function(data) {
        user.profile = data;
    });

    return user;

});
```

As `Accounts.onCraeteUser` is part of Meteor, I'm not sure what the best option is to return the data pulled from the request. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your call into an async wrapper (that converts it into a synchronous function).

Be aware this only works if the callback is something like `function(err, data)`.

In the code above you've used `function(data)`. I'm not too sure of any Twitter apis that do it this way. If you could check it is actually `function(err,data)` and if not I'll try edit the answer with something else

```
var getUserInfo = Meteor._wrapAsync(Twitter.get.userinfo.bind(Twitter.get));

user.profile = getUserInfo({screen_name: 'username'});
```

So what `Meteor._wrapAsync` does is it takes the function you give it and makes it synchronous on the server side. As soon as a result is returned in the callback, the second param (data) is returned.

If the first param, `err`, is returned it will throw it as an error.

Comment: Wow! The missing `err` was because I had wrapped the Twitter API in my own method but I've got it working using this method. Thanks!